# When migrating from EF to EF Core do you need to create a new migration with the entire database structure?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, migration, entity-framework-migrations, .net-6.0

I'm migrating an API from .NET Framework 4.7 to .NET 6 (including EF to EF Core) and when I create the `dbContext` and execute the `Add-Migration` command, it creates the whole structure of the database, which I'm scared of running because I'm not sure what could change.

Is this behaviour normal? Is there any way to avoid this "initial migration" or check beforehand if this migration causes any issue on the database?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct behaviour, EF Core migrations should be able to create full DB schema when called on **an empty DB**, so Add-Migration generate initial migration which will do exactly so (all existing EF4.7 migration won't be available for your EFCore 6 program).

At the same time, that initial migration will fail on **existing DB** because it already has all tables/columns/views.

Solution here is following: add code to the beginning of migration which checks whether one of the tables already exists:

- If yes, than DB structure is already match initial migration, nothing to do here (just exist)
- If not, this is blank DB and initial EFCore migration should be ran.

Here how check table existence inside migration: https://entityframeworkcore.com/knowledge-base/53473747/check-if-a-table-exists-using-ef-core-2-1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @pakeha_by. At least now I know that I'm going in the right direction, the issue I'm having with this is that EF Core is generating FK without underscore which is generating an exception when I'm accessing the db. Is that also normal? (EF 6 generates the FK with an underscore)